# RHEL6の古いkernelを削除しようとするとエラーになってしまう

Tags: linux, yum, rhel

### 困っていること

yum-utilsパッケージに含まれている`package-cleanup`を使用してkernelの保持世代数を変更しようとしているのですが、下記エラーが標準出力されてしまってできません。
どなたか解決策を教えてください。

### 環境

OS：RHEL6.9

実行コマンド：

```
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2
```

エラー内容：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/package-cleanup", line 27, in <module>
    from yum.misc import setup_locale
ImportError: No module named yum.misc
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/101331

Answer (score 1):

`package-cleanup`を`Python 2.7`で実行していて、`package-cleanup`に必要な`yum.misc`が`Python 2.7`用にインストールされていないためエラーが出てしまいました（ちなみに`Python 2.6`に関しては、`/usr/lib/python2.6/site-pacages/yum/misc.py`に存在していました）
なので、`package-cleanup`を2.6で実行するように変更して対処しました。

Answer (score 0):

環境変数`PYTHONHOME`に値が設定されていないか確認し、もし設定されているようなら値を空(未定義)にした状態で`package-cleanup`を実行し直してみてください。

```
unset PYTHONHOME
```

参考：
[システムで yum が失敗し No module named yum エラーが発生する](https://access.redhat.com/ja/node/2769261)
[Python の環境変数でハマった - Bite Code](http://torakichi.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/02/27/201111)